# Key management for builds for embedded systems

Tags: key-management

Our medical device has embedded processors and a USB port used for firmware updates and logfile transfers.  The usual USB viruses are not a concern (no mechanism to load or execute them, wouldn't run in our unique environment).  However a secure upgrade method is required by a regulatory agency, in case of malicious attack by someone with a copy of the source code, build environment and schematics.

In learning about security, our current concept is to use signing and encryption for upgrades and to embed the public key.  Then we have to keep the private key private for the product lifetime, hopefully on the order of twenty years.

Is there a standard way to do that?  Keep it on a secure build server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal approach is to store your private key in a manner in which it can't be compromised by a human being. Meaning, a disgruntled employee can't just steal it and then create malicious updates which have been signed with your key.

You will want to look at Hardware Security Modules which are capable og being fed your update or install image and and outputting the signature. That hardware device is then maintained under strict physical security ("locked in a safe").

Comment: With that approach I imagine using a different (non-secure, available to developers) key pair for iterative in-house development and testing.  Only use the secure public key (involving access to the safe) for builds intended for release.

Comment: @Technophile - That's the standard practice.

Comment: @Technophile - Note that you can often still use the HSM without ever exposing the key itself - most HSMs will expose an API to pass data to be signed/encrypted, which you would call during the build process.  In many cases, the HSMs are designed to make the private key entirely non-recoverable, since it would be such a large target.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse - Using the "real" HSM for development builds would allow an attacker to create a signed and malicious update. That's one of the primary reasons for **not** allowing developer access to the HSM.

Comment: @JulieinAustin - So the "real" one is only used for pushes to master, or after QA signoff, or whatever.  You have to get a trusted build in the first place, where you can guarantee that all the changes are authorized, so adding automated production signing should actually be preferred.  If the HSM is physically elsewhere, or otherwise requires manual use, you now have to trust whoever is performing the signing, too.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse - Correct, though I'm old-school paranoid and I think "automated production signing" is just a horrible idea. But again, paranoid ...

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse  I'm thinking in terms of (as JulieinAustin wrote) the HSM literally being kept locked in a safe.  Given the stream of IT people coming through a department for twenty years, far too many scenarios end in:  "who could have taken it - the server room door was locked!",  "you did WHAT with it?!?", "hey, *our* HSM has a different serial number!", etc.  Once I was sent to fix some custom equipment that had apparently stopped working:  the receiver for its signal had been unplugged, by someone with access.  Never found out who, or what they were thinking.

Comment: @JulieinAustin - yes, but are you paranoid *enough*, and about the right things?  One question is:  what happens if the HSM dies, especially after 10+ years and the manufacturer isn't around any more?

Comment: @Technophile - Physical HSMs usually have specialized network interfaces, not a GUI, so it takes special setup to talk to it (and it's usually authenticated access as well).  The rest of your build infrastructure has to be protected to the same degree anyways, or you risk things like compromised compilers/replaced libraries, so your HSM isn't special in that regard.  Also, the new hotness is cloud-based devops, where you don't have (much, if any) dedicated physical hardware.

Comment: Also, about your last point - What happens when the HSM dies at 19 years?  What was your replacement plan in the first place?  If you go the physical route you probably want a backup anyways.  On your deployment side, you likely want to have a "next" key, because it's going to be expiring, so you need a way to update it.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse  the HSM is a physical device, with (I expect) software infrastructure to pass data to be signed through it.  We can make redundant backups of that software and our build infrastructure.  That of course doesn't apply to hardware.  Don't understand why "the new hotness" would be relevant here.  About the last thing you want to do with a medical device is hook it up to the Internet and expose it to DOS attacks, viruses, etc.

Comment: @Technophile - Devops is your build infrastructure, not your individual deployed devices.  So things like a physical safe on your premises can be removed (whether or not that's good or bad... :shrug:) - the idea being that there wouldn't be a physical device for any of your employees to steal.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse - Physical HSMs in secured locations is a pretty typical approach. My employer (a Fortune 500 company) uses that approach and I'm not worried an employee is going to walk off with it. For smaller companies there are other solutions than having a safe on premises, such as a bank safe deposit box, which only the officers can access. For extremely small companies (like the one I used to own), trusted friends are another solution for "off-site storage" for things which aren't as critical as an HSM. For super-critical things, I had a concrete-encased floor safe -- 12" of concrete ;)

Comment: @Clockwork-muse - my concern is not theft, more uninformed decision(s) by anyone with access, over twenty years.  Someone with the light of Cleaning and Organization in their eye:  "didn't use it this year?  Toss it!".  Uninformed: "what's this?  Dunno, looks old.  Chuck it in a box, see if anyone complains" - then they forget or leave, and IT loses the box.  Or Beliefs:  "DevOps is your build infrastructure", whatever that means here.  Imagine it as an unmarked envelope containing the signed deed to your house:  go ahead, leave it in a drawer in the office for two decades.  It'll be fine.